# Hangman program, running into problems updating output

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to make a little hangman style of program, but I am running into problems when it comes to saving correct guesses.

So far I have gotten to the point where the first correct guess outputs letters where needed, for example if a correct letter was a:

```
_ _ _ a _ _
```

But, whenever I go for the second guess, even if correct, it only prints out that correct guess and forgets the past correct guesses. For example, if b was a correct letter on the second guess:

```
_ _ b _ _ _
```

Here's my code

```
for letter in range(len_word):
    print('_', end=" ")


guess = input("The length of the word is " + str(len_word) + ". Guess a letter, or ask for a vowel ... ")

while wrong_guesses < 6:
    if guess in letters_in_word:
        for letter in range(len(given_word)):
            if given_word[letter:letter+1] == guess:
                print(guess, end=" ")
            else:
                print('_', end=" ")
        guess = input("The length of the word is " + str(len_word) + ". Guess a letter, or ask for a vowel ... ")
    else:
        wrong_guesses -= 1
        print("Your guess is not in the word, you have " + str(wrong_guesses) + " left.")
        guess = input("The length of the word is " + str(len_word) + ". Guess a letter, or ask for a vowel ... ")
```

What I want is, is if on my first guess I got a correct answer, and it outputed

```
_ _ _ a _ _
```

I want my next guess, if incorrect, to print out

```
_ _ _ a _ _
```

Comment: First, please indent your code.

Comment: Since `wrong_guesses` is the number of guesses left, the loop condition should be `while wrong_guesses > 0:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is how you're keeping track of the hangman. Right now, every time they guess correctly, you are printing blanks and revealing the correct letter. There are a number of ways to keep track of the guesswork. Consider using a list of characters and updating it each time they guess correctly like:

```
scoreboard = [_] * len_word

while incorrect_guesses < 6:
// get the guess
    any_correct = None
    for index, char in enumerate(hangman_word):
        if guess == char:
            scoreboard[index] = guess
            any_correct = True
    print(scoreboard)
    if not any_correct
        print("wrong guess message")
        incorrect_guess += 1
```

The idea is to have a string that is the true word and a list that is what you show to the user. The `index, char` piece just lets you go through the actual word and keep track of both what character you're looking at in the true string and where it is in the string.

(You want to use a list and not a string for the answer because strings are immutable and you are actually very invested in mutability--which makes a list the perfect candidate.)

Answer (score 0):

in your code

```
if given_word[letter:letter + 1] == guess:
    print(guess, end=" ")
else:
    print('_', end=" ")
```

there exist no implementation of storing the letter which already guessed.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize a guess_string as

```
guess_string='_'*len_word
```

Then if guess is correct  `guess_string = guess_string[:letter] + guess + guess_string[letter+1:]`  and then instead of printing out character by character you could just do `print(guess_string)` and to check whether the word was guessed completely just check `if '_' in guess_string`

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python so if you actually try out `guess_string[letter]=guess` you'll get an error.

Comment: You're right, so instead `guess_string = guess_string[:letter] + guess + guess_string[letter+1:] ` should work

Comment: Mmm yep but only if you're heavily invested in strings (better to just use a mutable type rather than copy a string over and over).

Answer (score 0):

I think using a dictionary as a translation table might be very cute for this. When you correctly guess a letter, you don't have to iterate through the characters in your output string to reveal the new letters. Instead, you simply print a translated output string using the most recent translation table. Initially, the translation table (dictionary) maps all the letters in the original word to "_". Any time you make a correct guess, the dictionary gets updated, and the mapping for that character is changed.

Note, my example is case-sensitive, though it wouldn't take much to make it case-insensitive. It also treats vowels like consonants (in the sense that you don't "buy" letters, you just make guesses) - this is just the most naive implementation I could come up with.

```
word = "foobar"

max_incorrect_guesses = 3
incorrect_guesses = 0

hidden_char = "_"

translation = str.maketrans(word, hidden_char * len(word))

while ord(hidden_char) in translation.values():
    if incorrect_guesses == max_incorrect_guesses:
        print("You've failed to guess the word.")
        break

    print(f"Revealed so far: {word.translate(translation)}")
    guess = input("Enter a guess: ")
    if len(guess) == 1 and guess in word:
        print("Correct!\n")
        translation.update({ord(guess) : ord(guess)})
    else:
        print("Incorrect.\n")
        incorrect_guesses = incorrect_guesses + 1
else:
    print(f"Good job! the word was \"{word}\".")
```